# How does Chrome update URL bar completions?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, trie

I really enjoy using Chrome's URL bar because it remembers commonly-visited sites and often suggests a good completion based on what I've typed and/or visited before. So, for example, I can type `t` in the URL bar and Chrome will automatically fill it in with `twitter.com`, or I can type `maps` and Chrome will fill in the `.google.com`. This gives me the convenience of data-driven domain name shortcuts without having to maintain an explicit list.

What I'm wondering, though, is how Chrome determines that an old shortcut should be replaced with a new one. For example, if I visit `twitter.com` often, then that becomes the completion when I type `t`. But if I then start visiting `twilio.com` often enough, then, after some time, Chrome will start to fill that in as the default completion for `t`. What I can't figure out is how or when that transition takes place. It also seems that there are (at least) two cases involved : one for domain names, and another for path strings, because if I visit a certain full URL often, and then want to get to the root of the same domain, I end up having to type the entire domain name out to get Chrome to ignore the full-URL completion.

If I had to guess, I'd imagine that Chrome stores the things that I type in the URL bar in a trie whose values are the number of times that a particular string has been typed (and/or visited ?). Then I'd imagine it has some sort of exponential decay model for the "counts" in the trie. But this is just a guess. Does anyone know how this updating process happens ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I ended up finding some answers by having a look at the Chromium source code ; I'd imagine that Chrome itself uses this code without too much modification.

When you type something into the search/URL bar (which is apparently called the "Omnibox"), Chrome starts looking for suggestions and completions that match what you've typed. To do this, there are several "providers" registered with the browser, each of which knows how to make a particular type of suggestion. The URL history provider is one of these.

The querying process is pretty cool, actually. It all happens asynchronously, with particular attention paid to which activity happens in which thread (the main thread being especially important not to block). When the providers find suggestions, they call back to the omnibox, which appears to merge and sort things before updating the UI widget.

## History provider

It turns out that URLs in Chrome are stored in at least one, and probably two, sqlite databases (one is on disk, and the second, which I know less about, seems to be in memory).
This [comment at the top of HistoryURLProvider](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/45.0.2435.7:chrome/browser/autocomplete/history_url_provider.h;l=31;drc=3812f0b74098c7648f0341a3bea645330c092516) explains the lookup process, complete with multithreaded ASCII art !

## Sqlite lookup

Basically, typing in the omnibox causes sqlite to run this [SQL query for looking up URLs by prefix](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/37.0.2062.99:chrome/browser/history/url_database.cc;l=276;drc=cd05b97364507693c99110f642c611c929252cd4). The suggestions are ordered by the number of visits to the URL, as well as by the number of times that a URL has been typed.

Interestingly, this is not a trie ! The lookup is indeed based on prefix, but the scoring of those lookups does not appear to be aggregated by prefix, like I'd imagined.

I had a little less success in determining how the scores in the database are updated. This part of the code [updates a URL after a visit](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/32.0.1700.99:chrome/browser/history/history_backend.cc;l=737;drc=7492bc1fe1f20ffde4fcd29b09846d77f5e83566), but I haven't yet run across where the counts are decremented (if at all ?).

## Updating suggestions

What I think is happening regarding the updating of suggestions -- and this is still just a guess right now -- is that the in-memory sqlite database essentially has priority over the on-disk DB, and then whenever Chrome restarts or otherwise flushes the contents of the in-memory DB to disk, the visit and typed counts for each URL get updated at that time. Again, just a guess, but I'll keep looking as I get time.

The code is really nice to read through, actually. I definitely recommend it if you have similar questions about Chrome.

Comment: For a while now, the omnibox has been working well, in a nice and predictable way. But recently, for no known reason, its has changed things.

For instance, `r` used to autocomplete to `http://www.reddit.com/`, it now autocompletes (bizarrely) to `reddit.com/r/HistoryPorn/`, an interesting subreddit that I do visit, but not all that often.

I want the old behavior back! I wish there were a clear way to edit the priority of autocompletes in some override. Anyone know why this has happened or

Comment: @weemattisnot this recently started happening to me out of the blue as well. Chrome just seems to be autofilling to the longest version of that URL when in reality I just want the homepage. Were you able to solve it?